# Javascript not able to replace text with new Text with html

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to replace text with new text inside a html tag like:

```
  text = " hello how are you? " ;
  newText = "<h1>hello how are you? </h1> " ;
```

This is my code:

```
//replacer holds the html element
 var replacer = document.getElementById("#"+id);

 var newElement = "<span style='font-size:100px;' id='one4'>"+selectedinnerText+"</span>";

//selectedinnerText holds the text to be replaced                                                                 
 alert(selectedinnerText + "      "+ newElement   );

//This below line is not working properly
replacer.innerHTML = replacer.innerHTML.replace(selectedinnerText,newElement);
```

Comment: In your debugger, set a breakpoint on the `var replacer` line, then examine its value after stepping over that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, when you are getting an element by its id in JavaScript, you do not need *#* infront of the id name.

```
var replacer = document.getElementById(id);
```

So, the reason why you cannot set the `innerHTML` of the `replacer` element is because there is no element stored in the variable right now.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code should be

```
 var replacer = document.getElementById(id);// no # needed here
 var newElement = "<span style='font-size:100px;' id='one4'>"+selectedinnerText+"</span>";

alert(selectedinnerText + "      "+ newElement   );

replacer.innerHTML = replacer.innerHTML.replace(selectedinnerText,newElement);
```